# Crossdomain ServiceWorker load balancing

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm trying to implement smth like crossdomain load balancing with ServiceWorker API.

My concept is:

1. After install on every request on fetch event I try to access main domain (https://example.com/)
2. If success I should return this to user with like `event.respondWith(__response)`;
3. If failed (timed out or any other exception) I make CORS request to other server (https://balancer.com/) which returns other accessible domain (https://mirror1.example.com) and browser is redirected;

And I'm stucked on redirection step(((
So my current code is here

```
self.oninstall = function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
};

self.onactivate = function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
};

self.initialUrl = false;
self.onfetch = async function (event) {
    if (!self.initialUrl)
        self.initialUrl = event.request.url;


    if (self.initialUrl) {
        event.respondWith(self.tryAccess(event))
    } else {
        event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
    }
};

self.tryAccess = async (event) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        self.clients
            .matchAll({type: 'window'})
            .then(async (clients) => {
                for (var i in clients) {
                    var _c = clients[0];
                    if (_c.url === event.request.url) {
                        try {
                            let __tryResponse = await fetch(event.request);
                            resolve(__tryResponse);
                            return;
                        } catch (e) {
                            let __json = await (await fetch("https://balancer.com/")).json();
                            return _c.navigate(__json.path).then(client => client.focus());
                        }
                    } else {
                        resolve();
                    }
                }
            });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting a reference to a `WindowClient` and forcibly changing its URL from inside of a `fetch` handler isn't the right way to redirect.

Instead, inside of your `fetch` handler, you can respond with a redirection response created by [`Response.redirect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/redirect). From the perspective of the browser, this will be treated just like any other redirection that might have originated from the server.

One thing to note is that if you initially request a subresource via a same-origin URL that results in a redirect to a cross-origin response, you might run into some issues. If your original requests are for cross-origin URLs and your potential redirects are also to cross-origin URLs, I think you'll be fine.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  const fetchWithRedirection = async () => {
    try {
      // Use fetch(), caches.match(), etc. to get a response.
      const response = await ...;

      // Optional: also check response.ok, but that
      // will always be false for opaque responses.
      if (response) {
        return response;
      }

      // If we don't have a valid response, trigger catch().
      throw new Error('Unable to get a response.');
    } catch (error) {
      // Use whatever logic you need to get the redirection URL.
      const redirectionURL = await ...;

      if (redirectionURL) {
        // HTTP 302 indicates a temporary redirect.
        return Response.redirect(redirectionURL, 302);
      }

      // If we get to this point, redirection isn't possible,
      // so just trigger a NetworkError.
      throw error;
    }
  };

  // You will probably want to wrap this in an if() to ensure
  // that it's a request that you want to handle with redirection.
  if (/* some routing criteria */) {
    event.respondWith(fetchWithRedirection());
  } else {
    // Optionally use different response generation logic.
    // Or just don't call event.respondWith(), and the
    // browser will proceed without service worker involvement.
  }
});
```